# PHP $_GET['myval'] Help needed

Tags: php

What does following statement means

```
$tmp = @$_GET['myValue'];
```

Can somebody please provide detailed explanation on above statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The @ symbol is an error suppressor operator. It is not recommended to use it everywhere. Also, it is twice slower than the isset() function.
See full reference for the @ error control operator at http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Answer (score 2):

Please see the documentation and examples [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

Answer (score 1):

It assigns value of GET parameter `myValue` into `tmp` if exists. If not - then `tmp = null`

PS: it is a bad practice. Better way to do the same is:

```
$tmp = isset($_GET['myValue']) ? $_GET['myValue'] : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ :  to avoid warning 

$_GET : An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the URL parameters.

myval : parameter
```

--

example

```
http://example.com/?myval=test
echo @$_GET['myval']; will echo test

http://example.com/
echo @$_GET['myval']; will be null
//php 5.4 way is
var_dump(isset($_GET['myValue']) ? : null);
```